# Laravel validation rule based on other fields value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I have this radio button

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="discount" value="Yes">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="discount" value="No" checked>
```

and this hidden field

```
 <input type="hidden" name="discount_valid" value="true">
```

by default this hidden field is true

Now when i'm trying to validate if `discount_valid` is `true` then it should submit the form this code is working but i want to add another condition, if `discount` is `No` then it should submit the form irrespective of whether `discount value` is `true` or `false`. If discount is `Yes` and `discount_valid` is false then form should not submit.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'discount_valid'=>'in:true',
]);
```

Comment: @Udo E I'm using this `'discount_valid'=>'in:true'` but i want to add one more condition like `'discount_valid'=>'in:true' && discount==YES`

Comment: @UdoE.But before processing the form request i want to validate the form validation on hidden field is working but i want to add radio button group validation also, if discount==Yes then only i want to validate the hidden field else my form should submit

Comment: I believe you're abusing the purpose of Stack Overflow tags. [laravel-5] or [laravel-8] . Which is which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "submit the form", I have to assume you mean "processing the form request".

I've constructed a validation rule from your specifications:

> if discount_valid is true then it should submit the form

> if discount is No then it should submit the form irrespective of whether discount value is true or false

> If discount is Yes and discount_valid is false then form should not submit.

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'discount_valid'=>'exclude_if:discount,No|in:true',
                'discount'=>'in:No'
             ]);
```